# QTextEdit default value

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtextedit

i am using pyqt5 and i am wondering how i can set a default text to a textedit widget? So that it shows for example "Type your name here" and when i type something the text goes away. Like on login pages. I am happy about every answer!

it should look like this:

[image: here]

disclaimer: I already searched on the internet but found nothing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use property [`placeholderText`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#placeholderText-prop) :

```py
text_edit.setPlaceholderText("Search")
```